# BaseGameUtils in libgdx Project - Failed to find build tools revision 20.0.0

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle sync fails and the following message appears:

```
failed find Build Tools revision 20.0.0
```

In Android studio, i've installed the google play services packages from the sdk manager. I created a folder libraries in the root of project and in this folder i placed the BaseGameUtils. I modified the line

```
include 'desktop', 'android', 'core', ':libraries:BaseGameUtils'
```

in the gradle.settings file.
i also edited the build.gradle file,it now looks like this:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        }
        dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
       appName = "TapTapSort"
        gdxVersion = '1.6.5'
        roboVMVersion = '1.6.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.6.0'
        aiVersion = '1.5.0'
        gdxUtilsVersion = '0.11.0';
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0+"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils:$gdxUtilsVersion"
        compile "net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils-box2d:$gdxUtilsVersion" // Box2D module
    }
}

project(":libraries:BaseGameUtils")

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

build.gradle of BaseGameUtils:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
    if (!hasProperty('appcompat_library_version')) {
        ext.appcompat_library_version = '20.0.+'
    }
    if (!hasProperty('support_library_version')) {
        ext.support_library_version = '20.0.+'
    }
    if (!hasProperty('gms_library_version')) {
        ext.gms_library_version = '7.8.0'
    }

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompat_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:${gms_library_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:${gms_library_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:${gms_library_version}"
}

android {
    // Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
    if (!hasProperty('android_compile_version')) {
        ext.android_compile_version = 20
    }
    if (!hasProperty('android_version')) {
        ext.android_version = '20'
    }

    compileSdkVersion android_compile_version
    buildToolsVersion android_version
}
```

and here is a screenshot of the installed tools:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build tools version in your gradle setup needs to match the one you have installed. For some reason, your SDK manager is not showing your current build tools version, but I'm assuming its the latest, 23.0.0.

In your **build.gradle** file in the **android** directory, change

```
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
```

to

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
```

or maybe (not sure if this works):

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.*"
```

**Edit:**
Based on your update. I can't test this right now to be sure, but I think BaseGameUtils is looking for you to define `buildToolsVersion` and `compileSDKVersion` in a block called `ext` in your project's root.

So at the top of your root's build.gradle you could put

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 23 //or whatever you have installed
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"
}
```

And in your build.gradle in the android directory, change these two lines to refer back to the same `ext` block:

```
android {
    //...
    compileSdkVersion = ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion = ext.buildToolsVersion
    //...
}
```

Not sure, but you might need to replace `ext.` with `rootProject.ext.`. And maybe also change it in BaseGameUtil's build.gradle.

Comment: That's already configured. I modified this post and added the build.gradle of BaseGameUtils, i think the problem could be found there?

Comment: I think the baseGameUtils's gradle file is looking for an `ext` block in your project's root's build.gradle. One that defines the android buildToolsVersion and compileSDK version. See edit.